# UNIX Beginner: grep save to a file doesn't work

Tags: bash, unix, grep, io-redirection

Am a beginner in unix and I have just landed into a snag. The bash app I am working on is very simple and is one that can add contacts, and remove contacts (based on first and last name). Below is a part of my code, and for some reason, the grep displays the remaining contacts fine when excluding the (>contacts_file), but doesn't save to the file when including (>contacts_file). It instead leaves the 'contacts_file' blank. How can I fix this? Or is there a better way to search contacts in a contact's file? format in contacts_file is: firstname lastname

```
echo "[Remove a contact]"
echo "First Name: "
read first0
echo "Last Name: "
read last0  
grep -vw -e "$first0 $last0" contacts_file >contacts_file
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot direct output to the same file in which you are grepping.
The reason is that the shell opens that output file for writing and hence makes it empty.

The solution is to direct output to a temp file and then move the temp file to `contacts_file` if you want to replace it.